# HashMap search and match regex

Tags: java, regex, search, hashmap, match

I am trying to search on a HashMap and match specific string to nodes which represent string.

For matching exactly specific value it would have been done like this:

```
       for (Entry<String, Component> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue().toString().matches("test1")){
                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Nothing found");
            }
        }
```

But I have different case. The node contains long string `"xxx .. test 1 .."`

So, how can I match "test 1" to these node strings?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use indexOf:

```
if ( entry.getValue().toString().indexOf("test 1") != -1 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is see if `test 1` is in the string, you can use the String.contains() method.

```
if(entry.getValue().toString().contains("test1")){
   System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString());
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Nothing found");
}
```